# URL and Navigation links not changing when autoheight is used with autoscrolling in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js plugin and I have a couple of auto height sections defined using this class fp-auto-height.

In the JS, i have autoScrolling: false, fitToSection:false.

The issue is, on any section where fp-auto-height is defined, the URL doesn't change when you scroll to that section. Neither does the navigation links at the top. I also have tried increasing the padding top and bottom by 300px but that did not help.

I created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kdy56gjm/)

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({ 
    sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'pink', '#ccddff'], 
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage'], 
    menu: '#menu', 
    autoScrolling: false, 
    fitToSection:false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `autoScrolling:false` fullpage.js will consider you are in the section which shows more content within the viewport.

In your case, the small sections seem to take less viewport than the previous one and therefore fullpage.js consider you stay in the previous section.

There's no solution for your problem from fullpage.js's side at the moment.